# Trying to setup lamp and wordpress on kitematic for docker

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

I am using the following github repositoryies to setup images on [kitematic](https://kitematic.com/) for docker.

https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-lamp

https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-wordpress

I have them both installed as imags. The docker-lamp gives me a hello world cant connect to local mysql server, and the wordpress just doesnt work at all.

Here are the logs from each in order

lamp logs

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad9c56cb817dd619caf8

wordpress logs

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/225fad3840327dec39ea

Comment: Disable "Volumes",  it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

[Wordpress has an official image on docker hub/store](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/). If You want to use it, the easiest way is to use kitematic v0.17.1 (it has links/network tab in container detail), you can run it even in linux. You'll need to download Wordpress and Mariadb containers, and setup a link between the containers, setting the link alias as 'mysql' so Wordpress container uses envoriment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The tutum images should work out of the box.

Open Kitematic, and search for tutum images using tutum as the keyword. Find the lamp and wordpress images, and click create to create the containers.

They should just run.

Hope this helps!